# Cannot boot Windows--EFI shell issue

Tags: linux, boot, shell

I have a dual-Xeon system built for me in 2016, originally as dual-boot into Windows and Linux. As I never used the latter, the builder changed the boot to go into Windows by default. Worked fine, booting into Windows 10 Pro till 11/2022. Now it boots to a Shell command prompt.

Shell> EFI Shell version 2.40  Current running mode 1.1.2

Device Mapping table

Disk 0: HardDisk–Alias (null)  Pci Root (0x0)/Pci etc

Disk 1: through Disk 6

In BIOS boot manager, I see 6 items, including "Hard Disk" and "Built-in EFI Shell" but no "Windows Boot Manager".

I know something about Windows but nothing about EFI Shell or BIOS, which I can boot into. Would a Windows clean install fix the issue or is there something short of that I can do?

Thanks, Harmonia

Comment: Can you back to the builder and ask them to fix it?

Comment: First, the good news: it is highly likely this can be fixed without reinstalling everything. Do you have access to another PC to create a Windows Setup USB (for the built-in rescue shell)? Do you know which drives (HDD/SSD) are in the PC?

Comment: Within the EFI Shell, can you run `fs0:` (fs1:, etc) and `dir` to access any partition that contains an "EFI" directory? Within those partitions, does `cd EFI\Microsoft\Boot` work? If it works, does running `Bootmgfw.efi` (within the EFI\Microsoft\Boot directory) start Windows?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Builder has long since disappeared. I have access to another PC to create Windows Setup USB. I have already created a Windows 10 USB install (Windows Pro 22H2) but that's for a clean install. You are probably referring to a different "Windows Setup USB" for rescue shell. Where would I get that?   I will try your ideas from withing the EFI Shell.

Comment: Did you try to remove Linux from the boot when this happened? If you did not, then your disk has experienced a catastrophic error. Use a Linux Live USB to boot and save your data.

Comment: Daniel, I am ready to create the Windows Setup USB if you can guide me in that.

Comment: Harrymc,  This problem arose in 11/2022, likely in conjunction with the latest Windows Feature update. My data is already saved in a Macrium Reflect image, which I tried restoring to no avail--not surprising as I don't have Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: User186, I tried all the commands you recommended to no avail. "fs0:" "invalid mapping name".   "dir"   "Can't open current directory-no mapping."

Comment: The Setup USB drive you want is the one you have now. It has rescue built-in since Windows… Vista? // Again: Do you know which drives (HDD/SSD) are in the PC? If yes, please add this information to your question.

Comment: Daniel: I already tried the repair option on the Windows install USB drive but did not help. The PC should have a C: drive (GPT) and D: drive (MBR) according to my Reflect PE USB drive.